# React Redux QUIZ

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to make a simple Quiz work with Redux following this example in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5130417/Quiz-Application-in-React-Using-Redux . Somehow I think the quizLoad Reducer is not getting the data or isn't even being called correctly.

This is my Reducer:

```
const QUIZ_LOAD = 'QUIZ_LOAD';
const QUIZ_ANSWER = 'QUIZ_ANSWER';
const QUIZ_SUBMIT = 'QUIZ_SUBMIT';
const PAGER_UPDATE = 'PAGER_UPDATE';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  quiz: {
      config: {
          'allowBack': false,
          'allowReview': false,
          'autoMove': true,  // if true, it will move to next question automatically when answered.
          'duration': 0,  // indicates the time in which quiz needs to be completed. 0 means unlimited.
          'pageSize': 1,
          'requiredAll': false,  // indicates if you must answer all the questions before submitting.
          'richText': false,
          'shuffleQuestions': false,
          'shuffleOptions': false,
          'showClock': false,
          'showPager': true,
          'theme': 'none'
      },
      questions: []
  },
  mode: 'quiz',
  pager: {
      index: 0,
      size: 1,
      count: 1
  }
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  console.log('REDUCERRRRRRRRR')
  switch (type) {
    case PAGER_UPDATE:
      return { ...state, pager: payload, mode: 'quiz' };

    case QUIZ_LOAD:
      return { ...state, quiz: payload };

    case QUIZ_SUBMIT:
      return { ...state, mode: payload };

    case QUIZ_ANSWER:
      return { ...state, quiz: payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// <<<ACTIONS>>>
export const pagerUpdate = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: PAGER_UPDATE,
    pager: payload,
    mode: 'quiz'
  };
};

export const quizLoad = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: QUIZ_LOAD,
    quiz: payload
  };
};

export const quizSubmit = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: QUIZ_SUBMIT,
    mode: { payload }
  };
};

export const quizAnswer = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: QUIZ_ANSWER,
    quiz: { payload }
  }
};
```

This is my component and where I get the error

> "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'config' of
>   undefined eval
>   C:\Users\Willkommen\Documents\MyPension\REPOs\web-best\src\pages\header\vertragsCheck\index.js:69:6"

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Quiz from "./quiz/Quiz";
import {
  pagerUpdate,
  quizLoad
} from "redux/vertragsCheck/vertragscheckReducer";

import SEOTitle from "components/SEO/seoTitle";
import WavySectionWrapper from "components/Layouts/Containers/wavySectionWrapper/wavySectionWrapper";
import WavyPageTitleWrapper from "components/Sections/WavyPageTitle/WavyPageTitle";
import Button from "components/Button/Button";
import "./vertragsCheckSteps.scss";

const bgMobileImage =
  "/images/illustrations/pages/Home/mobile/mobile-phone1.png";

class vertragsCheck extends React.Component {
  state = {
    // quizes: [
    //      { id: 'data/myPensionQuiz.json', name: 'VertragsCheck' },
    //    { id: 'data/myPensionTest.json', name: 'Rente' }
    // ],
    quizVisible: false,
    quizId: "quizApi/quiz.json"
  };

  pager = {
    index: 0,
    size: 1,
    count: 1
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.load(this.state.quizId);
  }

  load(quizId) {
    let url = quizId || this.props.quizId;
    fetch(`../${url}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        let quiz = res;
        quiz.questions.forEach(q => {
          q.options.forEach(o => (o.selected = false));
        });
        debugger;
        console.log("quizCONFIG", this.props.quiz);
        quiz.config = Object.assign(this.props.quiz.config || {}, quiz.config);
        this.pager.count = quiz.questions.length / this.pager.size;
        this.props.onQuizLoad(quiz);
        this.props.onPagerUpdate(this.pager);
      });
  }

  // onChange = (e) => {
  //    this.setState({ quizId: e.target.value });
  //    this.load(e.target.value);
  // }

  handleClick = () => {
    const { quizVisible } = this.state;
    this.setState({ quizVisible: !quizVisible });
  };

  render() {
    const quizVisible = this.state.quizVisible;

    if (!quizVisible) {
      return (
        <WavySectionWrapper vertical>
          <SEOTitle page="vertrags-check" />
          <WavyPageTitleWrapper>
            <div className="flex-container">
              <div>
                <h1>
                  Kostenloser <br />
                  Vertrags-Check
                </h1>
                <p>
                  Ist meine bestehender Vertrag zu teuer? <br />
                  Wie schneidet meine bestehen Altervorsorge ab? <br />
                  Wir helfen Dir Deine Altervorsorge zu optimieren.
                </p>
                <Button size="sm" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                  Jetzt prüfen
                </Button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src={bgMobileImage} alt="myPension mobile graphic" />
                {/* <img
                    src="/images/background-elements/bg-vertical-section.svg"
                  /> */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </WavyPageTitleWrapper>
        </WavySectionWrapper>
      );
    } else if (quizVisible) {
      return (
        <Quiz
          quiz={this.state.quiz}
          quizId={this.state.quizId}
          mode={this.state.mode}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { ...state.quiz };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onQuizLoad: payload => dispatch({ type: quizLoad, payload }),
  onPagerUpdate: payload => dispatch({ type: pagerUpdate, payload })
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(vertragsCheck);
```

And this is my quiz data in public folder:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Vertrags-check Quiz",
    "description": "Vertrags-check Quiz determines if your actual pension contract is improvable",
    "config": {
        "showPager": false,
        "allowBack": true,
        "autoMove": true
    },
    "questions": [
        {
            "id": 1010,
            "name": "Sind die Effektivkosten höher als 1,5%?",
            "questionTypeId": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 1055,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Ja",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1056,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Nein",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1057,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Weiß nicht",
                    "isAnswer": true
                }
            ],
            "questionType": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test type",
                "isActive": true
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1011,
            "name": "Liegt Dein Rentenfaktor unter 27€?",
            "questionTypeId": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 1055,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Ja",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1056,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Nein",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1057,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Weiß nicht",
                    "isAnswer": true
                }
            ],
            "questionType": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test type",
                "isActive": true
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1012,
            "name": "Erfolgt die Anlage zu weniger als 80% in Aktien?",
            "questionTypeId": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 1055,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Ja",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1056,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Nein",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1057,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Weiß nicht",
                    "isAnswer": true
                }
            ],
            "questionType": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test type",
                "isActive": true
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1013,
            "name": "Ist Deine Rendite geringer als 3% p.A.?",
            "questionTypeId": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 1055,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Ja",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1056,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Nein",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1057,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Weiß nicht",
                    "isAnswer": true
                }
            ],
            "questionType": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test type",
                "isActive": true
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1014,
            "name": "Zahlst Du für Flexibilität?",
            "questionTypeId": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 1055,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Ja",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1056,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Nein",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1057,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Weiß nicht",
                    "isAnswer": true
                }
            ],
            "questionType": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test type",
                "isActive": true
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1015,
            "name": "Es gibt keine Steuervorteile bei deinem bestehendem Vertrag?",
            "questionTypeId": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 1055,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Ja",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1056,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Nein",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1057,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Weiß nicht",
                    "isAnswer": true
                }
            ],
            "questionType": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test type",
                "isActive": true
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1016,
            "name": "Hast Du Deinen Vertrag nach 2005 abgeschlossen?",
            "questionTypeId": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 1055,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Ja",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1056,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Nein",
                    "isAnswer": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1057,
                    "questionId": 1010,
                    "name": "Weiß nicht",
                    "isAnswer": true
                }
            ],
            "questionType": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test type",
                "isActive": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you wrapping your component with `<Provider>` anywhere?

Comment: Hi Brian, yes, I do. There are many other reducers working on the app and they work just fine. I was just tasked as Junior devlpr with adding this quiz and this is the only one doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

---

There is problem probably here:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => { return { ...state.quiz } };
```

You are using object spread operator, which puts/maps content of the state.quiz into your props. Therefore there isn't any `quiz` in `this.props`.
Try to map the `state.quiz` to `this.props.quiz` this way:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => { return { quiz: state.quiz } };
```

You are also mapping actions to props incorrectly, try this:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onQuizLoad: payload => dispatch(quizLoad(payload)),
  onPagerUpdate: payload => dispatch(pagerUpdate(payload))
});
```

Comment: actually I was wrong, the scoping is correct there, got tripped by improper formatting. So it is indeed an issue with missing `quiz` in props.

Comment: Thanks lavor, but unfortunately this didn´t solve the issue. Somehow I think the "case QUIZ_LOAD" switch in my Reducer is never beeing called. I appreciate if you had any idea why.

Comment: You are welcome. You are not mapping action creators to props correctly too. See my edited answer.

Comment: Mmm... I tried and tried, but that didn´t solve the issue neither. Thanks for all your efforts Lavor, I think I will start from the beginning. I ám afraid I´ve already changed too many things without being sure what is now working and what not... Thanks for your time!